# Jquery Text Animation On Scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

Successful:
I am able to animate text count when div is scrolled to.

Problem:
1. It counts up and then back down. I need this to count up once only and stop.
2. I need the numbers to default on page load to 0. Currently they load to target number and reset to zero when the div is scrolled to.

Here is the code...

JQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $('#scroll-to').offset().top,
       hH = $('#scroll-to').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log((hT-wH) , wS);
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));    
        }
    });
});
        }
});
```

HTML

```
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="scroll-to">
<div id="shiva"><span class="count">200</span></div>
<div id="shiva"><span class="count">1000</span></div>
<div id="shiva"><span class="count">853</span></div>
<div id="shiva"><span class="count">154</span></div>
<div id="shiva"><span class="count">10</span></div>
<div id="shiva"><span class="count">87</span></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="talkbubble"><span class="count">1421</span></div>
<div id="talkbubble"><span class="count">145</span></div>
<div id="talkbubble"><span class="count">78</span></div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#shiva
{
  width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
}
.count
{
  line-height: 100px;
  color:white;
  margin-left:30px;
  font-size:25px;
}
#talkbubble {
   width: 120px;
   height: 80px;
   background: red;
   position: relative;
   -moz-border-radius:    10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius:         10px;
  float:left;
  margin:20px;
}
#talkbubble:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   right: 100%;
   top: 26px;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 13px solid transparent;
   border-right: 26px solid red;
   border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
}

.linker
{
  font-size : 20px;
  font-color: black;
}
```

UPDATE: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ox12xyt/)

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can you provide link to codepen jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks Sergio. Now added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest add 0 to the initial markup and the target to a data attribute

Something like this:

```js
$('.count').each(function () {
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $(this).animate({
        Counter: target
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));    
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shiva"><span class="count" data-target="200">0</span></div>
<div id="shiva"><span class="count" data-target="1000">0</span></div>
```

Also add a flag to your conditional to avoid running the counter multiple times which I'm guessing  is causing the first issue:

```
var runCounter = true;
if (wS > (hT+hH-wH) && runCounter ){
runCounter = false;
// rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Sergio Alen. I'll look at this code first thing in the morning when I'm back at the office. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The first part of your post resolved both issues. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ox12xyt/1/

Comment: Thanks so much Sergio!